# Tensorflow Keras LSTM Inference one input at a time

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I have the following Sequence tagging Keras model:

```py
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
  tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64, return_sequences=True),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(2)
])
```

This model in takes a sequence of vectors and predicts the logits for two classes.

In a real-time application, I get these vectors one at a time, every second, and I would like to perform inference only on the new vector I received such that the previous hidden state of the LSTM is used.

---

**For example**, if I just receive vectors and run:

```py
# Received a
model(a)
# Received b
model(b)
```

The model runs independently for the two vectors (`a` and `b`), and does not leverage the temporal information the LSTM stores in the hidden state after step `a`.

Is there a way to perform inference and use these states?

---

Example prediction code not using temporal information

```py
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('./.save/3jbry45d')
model.build(input_shape=(None, None, 25))

random_vec = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.random.randn(1, 1, 25))

for i in range(5):
    print(model.predict(random_vec))
```

Prints 5 times:

> `[[[ 0.11500816 -0.5686636 ]]]`

Comment: Use `model.predict` and it will work.

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist How can I confirm its actually using the previous hidden state rather than an entirely new one? Any source?

Comment: Easy. Feed it the same input vector twice and observe the output.

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist This always returns the same output. I added example code so you can see what I'm doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this then:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64,
                       batch_input_shape = (1, None, 64),
                       return_sequences=True,
                       stateful = True),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(2)
])
for _ in range(10):
    print(model.predict(np.ones(64)[np.newaxis, np.newaxis])[0, 0])
```

The vectors printed will be different so the memory is used.